# Using nuxt-child's layout instead of the parent's

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am using Nested Routes and `<nuxt-child>` with layouts on nuxt.js.

The parent is holding the `<nuxt-child>` component, which is viewing the parent's subroutes.

I want Nuxt to use the parent's layout whenever I'm on its route / subroutes, though if any child has its own layout, I want Nuxt to use it instead of the parent's for it and its subroutes.

My file arrangement is as such:

```
pages/
--- parent/
------ child.vue
--- parent.vue
layouts/
--- parentLayout.vue
--- childLayout.vue
```

**pages/parent.vue**

```
<template>
  <nuxt-child />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  layout: "parentLayout",
};
</script>
```

**pages/parent/child.vue**

```
<template>
  <span>child.vue</span>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  layout: "childLayout",
};
</script>
```

So based on this example:

I want Nuxt to use the layout '*parentLayout*' whenever I'm on the ***parent/*** route or subroutes, though I want to show a different layout - '*childLayout*' whenever I'm on ***parent/child*** or its subroutes.

The issue is, even if I go to parent/child, the layout that is being used is 'parentLayout' and not 'childLayout', which is because I am using `<nuxt-child>`.

I have tried using `this.$nuxt.setLayout()`, but Nuxt still seems to load the parent's layout first, which makes the rendering look off.

How do I overcome this issue and use the wanted layout for child.vue and it's subroutes?

Answer (score 0):

A solution for this is to conditionally set `layout` in the parent.

```
export default {
  name: 'Parent',
  layout ({ route }) {
    if (route.name === 'parent-child-id') {
      return 'childLayout'
    }
    return 'parentLayout'
  },
  data () {
    return {}
  }
}
```